# An easy variant of map color theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

So the problem is to prove or disprove (or find a lower bound)  that I can color equal sized disc with four different colors so that none of the touching disc shares the same color. In other words is it possible to color a set of touching circular disc in four (or less) colors such that none of the touching discs share the color ?

I am have been trying to solve this. Of course it can be directly said using 4 color theorem. But this should have a neater proof I think.

Comment: 4 colors are sufficient, and necessary for some such graphs. See the following: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92883/small-4-chromatic-coin-graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are a finite number of discs, then there must always be one on the edge with 3 or fewer neighbors.  The obvious inductive procedure is to remove this disc, inductively solve the smaller problem, then trivially select a color for the disc as you add it back.

Comment: Umm.. I am not sure I follow you. Can you elaborate ? In the meanwhile I think we can do it with only three colors also. But this is just  hit and try. I am still figuring out the proof.

Comment: Three colors won’t do. Here’s the smallest counterexample: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92883/small-4-chromatic-coin-graphs/92920#92920 To find a disk with at most 3 neighbors in a finite arrangement of equal-size disks, draw a big circle around the arrangement, then shrink or move it until it touches a disk $D$ at a point $P$. $D$ can’t have four neighboring same-size disks, because the points on $D$ where they’d touch must be at least $60^\circ$ apart on $D$’s circumference. They would span at least $180^\circ$ and intersect the tangent line to $D$ at $P$ and go outside the big circle.